# How to filter tags by category?

Tags: categories, filters, tags

is there a way to add a custom filter in the Tags admin page? I'd like to filter tags by category. I saw plenty of custom filter for the POSTS admin page, like this one that filter posts by format:

```
function add_post_format_filter_to_posts($query){
    global $post_type, $pagenow;
    if($pagenow == 'edit.php' && $post_type == 'post'){
        if(isset($_GET['post_format_admin_filter'])){
            $post_format = sanitize_text_field($_GET['post_format_admin_filter']);
            if($post_format != 0){
                $query->query_vars['tax_query'] = array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy'  => 'post_format',
                        'field'     => 'ID',
                        'terms'     => array($post_format)
                    )
                );
            }
        }
    }   
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','add_post_format_filter_to_posts');
```

but nothing for TAGS admin page. I'm pretty sure it's possible to convert that snippet to make it works on Tags admin page, but I honestly don't know where to start.

I have mutiple categories and want to add a custom filter to display only the tags used in a specific category. If you can help me find information about that, it would be great, thanks.

**EDIT**

It's the page Admin › Posts › Tags. I use tags for posts of different categories and I'm looking for a way to display all the tags related to a certain category. This would be much easier to re-use them into new posts form the same category. e.g.: I create a new post and need to add some tags, but first I want to check which one were already used in that particular category in case some can be used for that new post. The thing is that many tags are regularly used for posts in the same category and so, being able to display only the ones that was used for that specific category will help me to save time and searching the ones I need more quickly. Sorry if I was not clear. Anyway, there's not filter on that page, as you said, so there's probably no hook to add any.

Comment: Wow, I'm confused what kind of filter you want to achieve. On Tags page or any taxonomy page there is no filters at all, only sortable columns (name, slug, description, posts count by default). On tags page there is no categories. Did you mean you want to filter posts on post edit page where displayed categories and tags in the table?

Comment: Hi Anton, thx for your answer. I added some more explanation in my post (it was too long for a comment).

Comment: If you want to know which categories were used with each tag and you want to see this on tags edit page, maybe it's better to create custom column, where to show these categories for each tag. Like you see on posts edit page categories and tags which were used for each post.

Comment: Well I guess that's the best solution. But I finally opted for a completely different approach: Showing all used tags and be able to select them via a checkbox.
https://css-tricks.com/how-and-why-to-convert-wordpress-tags-from-flat-to-hierarchical/

Comment: I personally use hierarchically taxonomies quite often, but on admin site it's more practical display them in custom columns. When I use several taxonomies, I prefer to display them in columns as links. For example if it's a posts edit page, I have to 2 columns with custom terms. If I click a term from one column, I see filtered posts only from this term, if I click on a term from another column, I see posts which has BOTH terms, from first and second taxonomy. And visually I see all of them, don't need to refresh dropdown everytime. But it's only my experience.